# ngModel Angular Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.ngtsc(-998002)

Tags: angular

a todos tengo este problema pero revisando en otros foros de esta misma paguina web. La solucion aparante es importar el FormsModule en app.module.ts

**Adjunto mi codigo - app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**login.component.html**

```
 <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="single_billing_inp">
                                    <label>Email Address <span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email" placeholder="example@mail.com">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="single_billing_inp">
                                    <label>Password <span>*</span></label>
                                    <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" placeholder="type password">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Cual seria la solucion?

Answer (score 0):

Despues de horas de tratar buscar la solucion la encontre. Si esta bien que se importe FormsModules dentro de app.module.ts.

No obstante, se debe importar el FormsModules tambien en el modules.ts de los componentes que estas usando ngmodule. A continuacion un ejemplo:

[image: Iamgen1]

Como se puede ver en este componente tambien existe el auth-profile.component.module.ts y este tambien se debe importar FormsModules

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AuthProfileRoutingModule } from './auth-profile-routing.module';
import { AuthProfileComponent } from './auth-profile.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SharedModule } from 'src/app/shared/shared.module';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AuthProfileComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuthProfileRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
  ]
})
export class AuthProfileModule { }
```